# Can my manager make me wait around till shop is more busy without pay?

Tags: united-kingdom, manager, training, england

Context: I work at a restaurant in the UK. I am new and haven't yet completed the online training Program's I have been asked to complete. It's pretty much a zero hour contract (I think it's 12 hours) but I work about 40 a week.

Situation: recently, whenever the restaurant gets less busy, my manager asks me to go upstairs and complete some more training without pay. They essentially keep me on site without pay incase they get busy. Today certain conditions led me to believe that it wasn't going to get busy for the rest of the day. They asked me to go do the training and I assumed I'd be upstairs until they were closing up, which takes about 40 minutes.

I wasn't about to sit upstairs for 3 hours unpaid, so I politely let the manager know that I'd like to get back on pay or go home. They sent me home.

Am I in the wrong here? Can I be fired for this?

Comment: State? You should include which state, as labor laws vary. Also you should consider heading over to [LAW](https://law.stackexchange.com/) for these types of questions. Can a mod migrate this?

Comment: This sounds very much like a legal question.  You should ask a lawyer what your rights are.  We don't have all the information regarding your situation and so are unable to answer your question.

Comment: Assuming that you need to complete the online training and that it is reasonable that the online training is unpaid (which likely depends on national laws and the nature of the training), why wouldn't you want to complete it when you were planning on being at work anyway?  You've got to complete the training and the training is unpaid so if you spend 3 hours on that at work that's 3 hours you don't have to spend on your own time.  And, presumably, the problem solves itself shortly once you've finished the training.  If your concern is that the training should be paid, that's a different issue.

Comment: `I assumed I'd be upstairs until they were closing up, which takes about 40 minutes` and then `I wasn't about to sit upstairs for 3 hours unpaid`. I'm confused, since when was 40 minutes equal to 3 hours?

Comment: I think he was just adding context: ie he thought they were keeping him around for 2 hours 20 minutes so that he could help for 40 minutes.

Comment: Have you read your contract? Could they have sent you home for two hours but asked you to come back for 40 minutes to close up? Taking a belligerent attitude isn't always the best approach. As Justin pointed out you've got mandatory training to do you might as well do it even if you think this is unfair.

Comment: The issue here is that the OP is being kept onsite and not being paid for it. The online training stuff is a side issue. FWIW, in the US this is typical of the exploitative food-service industry where employers of low-skill jobs feel perfectly justified in toggling off and on the pay of workers as the whim strikes them-- like their people are AWS servers.

Answer (score 8):

As you've been with your employer for less than two years, you haven't yet acquired the right to claim for unfair dismissal, therefore your employer can simply fire you (so long as it isn't for a small number of reasons that are always illegal - e.g. on the basis of your race). This is independent of your conduct or anything else, so "yes, you can be fired for this".

Comment: Meta note: this information *clearly* falls under "[stuff any UK employer should know](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/29/are-employment-law-questions-off-topic/39#39)" and is therefore on-topic despite being legal advice.

Comment: The fact that this would be an employee asserting relevant statutory rights (I.E. right to being paid for work) then this actually does fall under constructive dismissal and time worked is irrelevant since the april 2012 update to the Employment Acts right (1996) to the best of my knowledge, but only applicable if he's actually figured which doesn't appear to have happened yet.

Comment: Actually fired* sorry

Comment: @PhilipKendall Can you repost your meta note on the question itself to preempt close votes?